# What is parperet hapat

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, maseches-pesachim

[Mishnah Pesachim 10:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.10.3) says:

> מְטַבֵּל בַּחֲזֶרֶת, עַד שֶׁמַּגִּיעַ לְפַרְפֶּרֶת הַפַּת
>
> [he] dips the lettuce until he reaches parperet hapat

What exactly does parperet hapat mean in this context? Various commentators seem to agree that it's a part of the seder, but they disagree on *which* part.

Comment: Are you specifically interested only in what part of the Seder is being referenced? The term is a general term used elsewhere as well (eg. Mishna Berakhot 6:5)

Comment: What’s wrong with the commentaries you’ve seen that you seek an answer here?

Comment: Rashi/Tosafot: Eating Maror. Bartenura: Eating matza. Tiferet Yisrael: Yachatz (Is that what you're looking for? If so I can write up as answer...)